# using if expression to change color numbers

Tags: angular, ionic4

l want to use `if expression` to change color of temperature coming form server , but l got error

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '30'
    at KeyValueDiffers.push.
```

code

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    let temp = value

    if (value>0 && value<10){
      return "dark-blue";
    }else if (value>11 && value<20){
      return "mid-blue";
    }else if (value>21 && value<30){
      return "light-blue";
    }else if (value>31 && value<39){
      return "aqua";
    }else if (value>40 && value<45){
      return "yellow";
    }else if (value>46 && value<49){
      return "light-orange";
    }else if (value>50 && value<70){
      return "red";
    }

    return temp

  }
```

any solution please ?

Comment: Do you use it in html like `myValue | myPipe` ?

Comment: yes l did `[ngClass]='item.temperature|tempture'`

Comment: Hmmm maybe `class="{{theTemperature | thePipe}}"` then it will write the piped classname there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because if you give 30 as input to your pipe and it returns 30, which is not a valid class name.

Make sure to return an empty class or a default color if nothing matches, and in your case maybe you want to change `<` for `<=` to handle 30.

Also, if your input is a number, type the value parameter as a number, and your output as a string:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'temperature' })
export class TemperaturePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    if (value > 0 && value <= 10) {
      return 'dark-blue';
    }else if (value > 11 && value <= 20) {
      return 'mid-blue';
    }else if (value > 21 && value <= 30) {
      return 'light-blue';
    }else if (value > 31 && value <= 39) {
      return 'aqua';
    }else if (value > 40 && value <= 45) {
      return 'yellow';
    }else if (value > 46 && value <= 49) {
      return 'light-orange';
    }else if (value > 50 && value <= 70) {
      return 'red';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but l need to `return temp` to work ! if l remove `return temp` the pipe will not working !

Comment: @Ali Ghassan, temp is a number, you can't bind it to a class, thus it is not a valid output for your pipe

Answer (score 0):

try using brackets around it:

```
(item.temperature | tempture) or "{{ item.temperature | tempture }}"
```

Also change your logic of if and else to cover all values.